# O(n^2) algorithm to retain shortest path after removing vertex

Tags: algorithm, graph, runtime, dynamic-programming, shortest-path

If I want to construct a O(n^2) algorithm that retains the shortest path distance of a graph after removing a vertex, should I approach this with dynamic programming and have a function store information about the shortest path in each double array box?

For example, I have a graph G and I take out a vertex to then have new graph G2. I want G2's shortest distance between all vertices to be equal to that of the original G

Comment: How can you achieve that? By modifying the weights of the edges? If that is your intent, please explicitly add it.

Comment: On second thought, it cannot be done with just modifying the weights, because you might make your graph unconnected. Please elaborate how you want to modify the graph in order to achieve G2 with same all-to-all shortest path.